# Find all $c \in \Bbb Z_5$ such that $\Bbb Z_5[X]/ \langle x^2+cx+1 \rangle$ be a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all $c \in \Bbb Z_5$ such that $\Bbb Z_5[X]/ \langle x^2+cx+1 \rangle$ be a field.

Attempts:

$\Bbb Z_5[X]/ \langle x^2+cx+1 \rangle$ be a field iff $p(x) = x^2 + cx +1$ is irreducible in
$\Bbb Z_5$ iff $p(x)$ has no roots in $\Bbb Z_5$. I found that $2 \ne c \in \Bbb Z_5$ are the answer.

Am I true?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: it means, $c \ne 3$ ?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't mean $c\ne-2$, but yes, it means that $c\ne3$ is necessary.

Comment: since $3 = -2$ in $\Bbb Z_5$

Comment: What about $c=0$? And what about $c=1$ and $c=-1$?

Comment: $x^2+1$ has no root

Comment: $2^2+1=3^2+1=0$

Comment: Oh, yes. I assume that it is in $\Bbb Z$

Comment: so, $c = 1 $ and $c=4$ are the answer ?

Comment: As usual (see the linked dupe) you need only test if the discriminant $\,c^2-4\equiv c^2+1\,$ is a square $\!\bmod 5,\,$ i.e. is one of $\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}^2\equiv  0,1,4,\,$ which is true $\iff c^2\not\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $\Bbb Z_5[X]/ \langle x^2+cx+1 \rangle$ is a field iff $x^2+cx+1$ has no roots in $\Bbb Z_5$.

For $c=0$, $x^2+1\equiv x^2-4=(x+2)(x-2)$ is reducible.

For $c=1$, $x^2+x+1$ is $1,3,2,3,1$ for $x=0,1,2,3,4$, respectively, so there are no roots.

For $c=2$, $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$ is reducible.

For $c=3$, $x^2+3x+1\equiv x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$ is reducible.

For $c=4$, $x^2+4x+1\equiv x^2-x+1$ is $1,1,3,2,3$ for $x=0,1,2,3,4$, respectively, so there are no roots.

Comment: nice same. thanks

Comment: i.e. it's solvable $\iff c^2\not\equiv 1,\,$ as I explain in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a little table of the values of $x^2+cx+1$, its values are $1,2+c,2c, -2c, 2-c$.
Hence see that $c=\pm 2$ and $c=0$ give reducible quadratics.

Comment: $x^2+1$ has root ?

Comment: the answer is $c=1$ and $c=4$ ?